# Sorting in Ruby doesn't do what I expect with sub arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I'm defining a method that should take a String array, slice it in pairs of 2 words and sort them.

However, the sorting isn't acting as I expect it to. It sorts an "s" before an "m" (for the pair "my say" it puts "say" before "my").

```
def sorted_pairs(array)
  puts "original: #{array}"
  new_array = array.each_slice(2).to_a
  puts "sliced: #{new_array}"
  new_array.sort #this line does nothing?
  puts "sorted: #{new_array}"
  return new_array
end

#test
words = %w(say my name say my name)
puts sorted_pairs(words)

expected: [["my", "say"], ["name", "say"], ["my", "name"]]
     got: [["say", "my"], ["name", "say"], ["my", "name"]]
```

sort! wont work either, as it will sort the pairs according to the element inside each pair (not sorting the pair itself).

```
expected: [["my", "say"], ["name", "say"], ["my", "name"]]
     got: [["my", "name"], ["name", "say"], ["say", "my"]]
```

Comment: If you want each subarray to be sorted then use map to sort each subarray. You may need to use sort_by

Comment: "It sorts an "s" before an "m" (for the pair "my say" it puts "say" before "my")." – Please, look at it more closely. It's not sorting "random". The result is simply "say my name say my name", so it clearly wasn't sorted "random", it wasn't sorted *at all*, which is something *very different* from "random".

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you're sorting the parent array, rather than the individual arrays within it. Try the following:

```
def sorted_pairs(array)
  array.each_slice(2).map(&:sort)
end

sorted_pairs(words)
#  => [["my", "say"], ["name", "say"], ["my", "name"]]
```

I've removed the `puts` lines for clarity, though feel free to keep them if you'd like. I've also refactored into a one liner as it’s pretty straightforward to read that way.

Please note that because `array.each_slice(2)` returns an Enumerator this uses `Enumerable#map`, whereas `array.each_slice(2).to_a` creates an unneeded temporary array and uses `Array#map`.

So, what we're doing is going through each pair of words (in a sub array) and calling [`sort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) on them, returning the sorted values (using [`map`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map)).

This means it will compare the individual pairs rather than comparing one sub array to another as in your current method.

Comment: ...and because `array.each_slice(2)` returns an `Enumerator` this uses [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), whereas `array.each_slice(2).to_a` creates an unneeded temporary array and uses [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map).

Comment: "Hope this helps - let me know how you get on :)". While you're trying to help and be friendly, remember that SO is neither a forum or a message board, it's like an online reference book of programming Q&A, so we write questions and answers in clear, concise and fluff-free style.

Comment: Thanks both, appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Did this help at all @1990eam?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you want:

```
new_array = array.each_slice(2).to_a
new_array.sort! {|a, b| a[0] <=> b[0]}
```

`sort` and `sort!` take a block which defines how to sort. In this case, we want to sort by the first element of the array. The `<=>` operator is used for cases like this.

---

I misunderstood the question. If we want to sort inner arrays, we can simply `map` it using `sort`, as @SRack [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60835621/1481210):

```rb
array.each_slice(2).map(&:sort)
```

Comment: It won't work either. Seems I have to find a way to sort the items inside each pair. !sort will sort each pair according to the first element in said pair.

Comment: This doesn't give the correct output, it gives: `[["my", "name"], ["name", "say"], ["say", "my"]]`.

Comment: I see I misunderstood your spec. Then @SRack answer is exactly what you want.

Comment: Please don't use "edit" or "update" tags when changing your text. Instead, simply edit it, and add the new information where you would have put it if it'd been there initially, On SO, readability is much more important than tracking the times of changes or their order; The system maintains change information on all modifications that we can look at if its necessary.

Comment: @MasafumiOkura - bit poor form to update to mimic my answer IMO?

Comment: @SRack sorry I updated my answer to refer your answer.